# Nuxt.js title and meta content 'undefined' when viewing page source

Tags: seo, nuxt.js

I am currently setting up titles and meta descriptions in a Nuxt.js application, but have encountered an issue. When I click 'View Page Source' the dynamic titles and meta content I set in the head() shows as 'undefined':

[image]

However, when I inspect the page this dynamic content shows as expected:

[image]

[image]

On each page I've set the title and meta as follows:

```
    head() {
      return {
        title: this.title + ' | CompanyName',
        meta: [
          {
            hid: 'description',
            name: 'description',
            content: this.description,
          },
        ],
      }
    },
```

Any suggestions as to why this is happening, and how to fix?

Answer (score 0):

I seem to have found a solution. In the above example the this.description and this.title were being populated from an API call in the mounted() function. If this is switched to an API call through asyncData() then when you view the page source, it is no longer undefined.

```
    async asyncData(context) {
      return context.$axios.get(`/endpoint`).then(result => {
          return {
            description: result.data,
          }
        }).catch(e => {
          context.error({ statusCode: 404, message: 'Error' })
        })
      }
```